# $f^*: Spec(A) \longmapsto Spec(B)$ is open implies $A$ and $B$ will satisfy going-down property

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra

> **[Atiyah-Macdonald, Exercise 5.10.(ii)]** $(a) \implies (b)$ basically asks us to show that if $f^*: Spec(B) \longmapsto Spec(A)$ is open, then $A \subseteq B$ will have going-down property, where $f$ is the inclusion map from $A$ to $B$.

Now there are a lot of solutions in the internet, but I think I have solved it properly by not using localization.

Open sets of spectrum of a ring are collection of prime ideals which doesn't contain a particular set. For example, if $S$ is a subset of a ring $A$, then $I(S) = \{p \in Spec(A): S \nsubseteq p \}$ is open in $Spec(A)$. Since $f^*$ is open, $f^*(I(S))$ will be open too.

So to show going-down property, suppose $p_1 \supseteq p_2$ are prime ideals of $A$, and $q_1$ is a prime ideal of $B$ such that $q_1 \cap A = p_1$. We need to find some prime ideal $q_2$ in $B$ such that $q_1 \supseteq q_2$ and $q_2 \cap A = p_2$.

Now $I(B \setminus q_1)$ is an open set in $Spec(B)$. Hence $f^*(I(B\setminus q_1))$ is open in $Spec(A)$.

Now $f^*(q_1) = p_1$, and $q_1$ definitely doesn't intersect $B\setminus q_1$, hence $q_1 \in I(B\setminus q_1)$. Similarly $p_1 \in I(A \setminus p_1)$. Hence $I(A \setminus p_1) \subseteq f^*(I(B\setminus q_1))$.

Suppose $p \in I(A \setminus p_1)$. Then $p$ doesn't intersect $A \setminus p_1 \implies p \subseteq p_1 = f^*(q_1) \in f^*(I(B \setminus q_1))$.

So we have shown that $I(A \setminus p_1) = f^*(I(B \setminus q_1))$. Then $p_1 \supseteq p_2 \iff p_2 \in I(A \setminus p_1)$. Hence $\exists q_2 \in I(B \setminus q_1)$ such that $p_2 = f^*(q_2) \implies q_2 \cap A = p_2$, and  $q_1 \supseteq q_2$.

It'll be great if anyone can check whether my solution is correct or wrong. Thanks in advance!